# Problem using bibtex with natbib - "couldn't open style file natbib.bst"

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am migrating across laptops. In my old laptop I have a .tex file which works just fine. However, when I use the same .tex and compile it in a new laptop in which I just installed the proTeXt system, it does not create the bibliography, and I get the message:

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "DTAGissues"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: DTAGissues.aux
I couldn't open style file natbib.bst
---line 37 of file DTAGissues.aux
: \bibstyle{natbib
 :                 }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file DTAGissues.aux
(There were 2 error messages)

Process exited normally
```

So, there seems to be a problem with natbib, but I don't understand it, as everything was working fine in my previous system. I use the lines below to include the bibliography:

```
%include the bibliography
\bibliographystyle{natbib}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliography{C:/ctr/MainBibFile}
```

What might I be doing wrong here?

I actually manege to make it work if I copy file natbib.bst into the folder where my .tex is, but that seems a patch rather than a solution? I tried adding natbib.bst to texmf folder but that does not work.

Comment: Type `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

proTeXt uses MiKTeX, so *basically* you may follow [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127410/510) answer which shows how to install additional packages "by hand" with MiKTeX. However, because you don't want to install a package file (`.sty`), but a BibTeX style file (`.bst`), you should replace the recommended subdirectory `tex\latex\misc` with `bibtex\bst\misc`.

A more important caveat (and the the source of your problem): The current version of the `natbib` package doesn't include a `natbib.bst` style file anymore. Googling for `natbib.bst` brings up [this](http://www.ra.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/lehre/ws13/systems_biology/natbib.bst) file from 1994 (!). It could be that `natbib.sty` (the package) is backward-compatible with `natbib.bst`; it could also be that the package and your `.bst`, even when installed correctly, don't play together well. So: check thoroughly if everything in your bibliography and in-text-citations is working as expected.